# How to mock a subprocess.check_call exception in python test

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am new to mocking in python

I wanted to mock an exception CalledProcessError coming out of subprocess.check_call, When the exception occurs I want to check if the ret value is 1.

when I mock the function call as below I get and error

```
def myFunc(cmd):
    try:
        ret = subprocess.check_call(cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        ret = 1

    return ret

def test_some_func():
    with mock.patch('subprocess.check_call', side_effect=subprocess.CalledProcessError("Exception")):
        ret = myFunc(["some_command"])
        assert ret == 1
```

I get and error

```
with mock.patch('subprocess.check_call', side_effect=subprocess.CalledProcessError("Exception")):
E       TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd'
```

Can anyone give me a hint about what is missing?
Is there a good tutorial/book about python mocking?

Answer (score 0):

After adding arguments to CalledProcessError was missing.

```py
def test_some_func():
    with mock.patch('subprocess.check_call', 
                     side_effect=subprocess.CalledProcessError('127',
                     'some_command'):
        ret = myFunc(["some_command"])
        assert ret == 1
```